# UILabel lineBreakMode, break at specific character

Tags: ios, uilabel, line-breaks

Is there a way to break the text in a `UILabel` at a specific character say ";" ??

I don't want it to be broken with Word Wrap or character Wrap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just replace all the occurrences of ";" with ";\n" before you show the string.

Answer (score 3):

There is another way which will work in limited circumstances.  You can replace your normal spaces (\U+0020) with non-breaking spaces (\U+00A0).  This will allow you to limit the number of places your string breaks.  For example if you had a string like;

```
I have a string with two sentences. I want it to preserve the sentences.
```

By carefully using non-breaking spaces you can get it to break like this;

```
I have a string with two sentences. 
I want it to preserve the sentences.
```

HOW:

For Strings in InterfaceBuilder:

Go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources -> +
Select the category 'Others' and the keyboard 'Unicode Hex Input'
Select 'Add'
Make sure 'Show Input method in menu bar' is selected.
CLose System Preferences

Go back to XCode and find your string
Using the keyboard menu in your menu bar, select the Unicode keyboard
In your string select a space.  Type Option+00a0.  A space will appear when you've completed the 4 digit sequence.  That space is a non-breaking space.  Repeat for all spaces you need to.

For programmatic strings you can just add \U00A0 as appropriate.

Comment: In Swift, programmatically you can do `"\u{00a0}"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `(\r)` instead of newline `(\n)` to create a line break.

Set `numberOfLines` to `0` to allow for any number of lines.

```
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Like With in your case just replace `;` with `;\n`

```
NSString *string = @"This; is a; NSString";

string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";"
                                     withString:@";\n"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't break line using `;` this character. if you want to break line then replace this character with `\n` character.

```
label.text=[label.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@"\n"];
```

And make

```
label.numberOfLines = 0.
```

And Update the label frame

```
CGSize labelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font  constrainedToSize:label.frame.size lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];

label.frame = CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x, label.frame.origin.y, label.frame.size.width, labelSize.height);
```

Comment: in my string multiple time ( , 0r ; ) then every time break line so, what can i do. in your answer is good for single time (, or ; ) and break line.

Comment: @Rock so when you want to break line for first ; or last ;?

Comment: last,  i have one paragraph for example paragraph consider 4 comma(,) so, this paragraph happen four line. every time new line after comma(,)  Thanks.

Comment: `label.text=[label.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"\n"];` please try to use this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with combination of newline character and line break.Check the following code,

```
self.testLabel.text = @"abc;\nabc;";

self.testLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

CGSize labelSize = [self.testLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.testLabel.font
                          constrainedToSize:self.testLabel.frame.size
                              lineBreakMode:self.testLabel.lineBreakMode];

self.testLabel.frame = CGRectMake(
                         self.testLabel.frame.origin.x, self.testLabel.frame.origin.y,
                         labelSize.width, labelSize.height);
```